# How to find and remove multiple sub strings in a string

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell

I have an input as follows

Input File Name : a.txt

> -- Some Comment
>
> delete from tb.Test WHERE id = 'abxd1';
>
> delete from tb1.Test WHERE id = 'abxd2';
>
> -- Some Comment
>
> delete from tb1.Table1 WHERE id = 'abxd3';

Expected output file : b.txt

> -- Some Comment
>
> delete from Test WHERE id = 'abxd1';
>
> delete from Test WHERE id = 'abxd2';
>
> -- Some Comment
>
> delete from Table1 WHERE id = 'abxd2';

The following code will just replace the value "tb.".  I am trying to make this as a generic script.

```
while read line
do
   str=$line
   echo "${str/tb./}" >>b.txt
done <$1
```

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sed`:

```
sed 's/delete from \(tb[0-9]\?\).\([[:alnum:]]\+\)/delete from \2/g' input.file
```

Comment: What do you mean with `sub string`?

Comment: what I meant to say is the some string that need to be removed, basically anything after "from"  till "."  In the above example "tb.", "tb1.". sorry for  not asking the question completely.

Comment: I don't get, I could just guess. You need to explain more.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `sed`:

```
echo $str | sed -r 's/tb[a-z0-9_]*.//g'
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to remove `X.` in `delete from X.Y` (everything before the DOT and the DOT), it is even simpler:

`sed 's/delete from .*\./delete from /' a.txt`

and you can use the `-i` option to overwrite the same file

`sed -i 's/delete from .*\./delete from /' a.txt`

HTH, Marcello

Comment: what if I want to remove anything after "delete from" to .(DOT including tb. tb1. or abc.), so the output will be delete from test ..

Comment: in that case: `sed 's/delete from .*\./delete from /' a.txt` (I've updated the answer above accordingly)